# Finding roots for algebraic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

Can anyone help me simplify this statement:

> $$x = \frac{(1-a)^2}{(1-xa)^2}$$

I multiplied the denominator by $x$ to get rid of the fraction, but I cannot figure out how to manipulate it to reach the common $(x-z)(x-y) = 0$. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you want: $x=$ function of $a$? or $a=$ function of $x$?

Comment: You will get one extra factor $(x-w) $ as it will be a cubic equation. Just cross multiply.

Answer (score 6):

Note that $x=1$ is a solution.

Taking $(1-ax)^2$ to the L.H.S and converting this into a cubic gives:
$$a^2x^3 - 2ax^2 + x - (1-a)^2 = 0$$
We can factor out an $(x-1)$ to give:

$$a^2x^3 - 2ax^2 + x - (1-a)^2 = (x-1)(a^2x^2 + (a^2-2a)x + (1-a)^2)$$

You can now look for other solutions by solving the quadratic.

Comment: okay are you able to help with the quadratic formula, I struggle doing it with variables sorry :(

Comment: You just have to plug stuff in. $$x = \frac{-(a^2-2a) \pm \sqrt{(a^2-2a)^2-4a^2(1-a)^2}}{2a^2}$$ and simplify the expression inside the square root sign.

Comment: Okay are the 2 solutions then x = (-1+a)/a and x = -2 + 3/a ?

Comment: That's wrong. They are: $$\frac{(2-a) \pm \sqrt{4a - 3a^2}}{2a}$$

Comment: ....with constraint $a\neq 0$

Comment: Of course. If you want to add constraints, might as well think about the stuff inside the square root sign. For real solutions you'd want $4a - 3a^2 \geq 0$